# I do not like Paypal. Any alternatives to support Ubuntu?

Tags: services

I want to help with a donation to you good people but cannot understand why you support the worst payment system in the world.

Kindly give me an alternative.

Comment: You don't need a PayPal account, actually: you can use a credit card through PayPal.

Comment: I changed your "fact" to an opinion. Paypal does work for some of us ;-)